Middleware redirecting issue to custom Login page with NextAuth 5 - NextJS 14
I have using NextJs 14 et NextAuth 5(beta).
I tried to setup custom login page with NextAuth. It is working fine except NextAuth redirection.
When I use the signIn method provided by NextAuth
import { signIn } from '@/auth'

When I clicked on it, I am redirected to /api/auth/signin instead of /auth/signin but I have the correct html, the one from /auth/signin (rewrite instead of redirect)
I would like to have the correct url in the navigator when I clicked on it.
Same problème with the verify-request, /api/auth/verify-request instead of /auth/verify-request
Here is my configuration auth
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import NodemailerProvider from 'next-auth/providers/nodemailer';
// import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

import { authConfig } from '@/auth-light';

const providers = [
  NodemailerProvider({
    server: {
      host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
      port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
      },
    },
    from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
  }),
  // Google
];

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request',
  },
});

My auth-light`
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter';
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';

export const authConfig = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
  providers: [],
};

export const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

And my middleware
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { auth } from '@/auth-light';

const authRoutes = ['/auth/signin', '/auth/verify-request'];

export default auth(async function middleware(request) {
  const currentUser = request.auth;
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname);
  const isHome = request.nextUrl.pathname === '/';

  if (currentUser) {
    if (isAuthRoute) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url));
    }
  } else if (!currentUser) {
    if (!isHome && !isAuthRoute) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/signin', request.url));
    }
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
};

Thanks for your help!
